# Loop iteration in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,x=10;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++);
    {
        x++;
    }
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

**Output :** 11

No matter how many times the for loop iterates, the value of x stays 11. Why is that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from here:

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++);
```

The semicolon makes the `for` loop have an empty body. It makes it equivalent to

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++){}
```

Including warning flags in your compiler(`-Wextra` in GCC) emits a warning about these kind of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon (**;** ) punctuation mark in C means that block of code is finished. That means if you use

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++);
    {
        x++;
    }
```

For loop ends before it reaches brackets. Then code between your brackets runs like normal lines out of loop. If you want your loop to include brackets, get rid of the semicolon, like:

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        x++;
    }
```